Density of states - as a function of electron velocity
A condensed matter textbook states that in a 3D gas of electrons obeying the Fermi-Dirac statistics the number of electrons per unit volume having velocity components in the ranges $u, u+d u$, $v, v+d v$, and $w, w+d w$ is given by
$$
n(u, v, w)\  du dv dw = \underbrace{2}_{Spin}\underbrace{\left(\frac{m}{h}\right)^3}_{Unclear} \underbrace{ \frac{1}{1 + e^{\left(\frac{1}{2} m\left(u^2+v^2+w^2\right)-\epsilon\right\} / k T}}}_{\text{Fermi-Dirac Distribution}} d u d v d w
$$
I don't understand where the the $\left(\frac{m}{h}\right)^3$ term arises.
I can see that for a free electron where velocity is given by $
    \mathbf{v}=\frac{\hbar \mathbf{k}}{m}, 
$ changing the differential between $d\vec{k}$ and $d\vec{v}$ is given by
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}k_x}{\mathrm{d}v_x}\frac{\mathrm{d}k_y}{\mathrm{d}v_y}\frac{\mathrm{d}k_z}{\mathrm{d}v_z} = \left(\frac{m}{h}\right)^3 $$
But I can't see why would be relevant here. I'd suggest I'm also missing the density of states, surely I'd need to multiple the Fermi-diract distribution by the density of states for a 3D gas, $g(\varepsilon)=\frac{V}{2 \pi^2}\left(\frac{2 m}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3 / 2} \varepsilon^{1 / 2}$.

The number of states, per unit volume in the momentum space and unit volume in real space is $h^3$ http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/phase.html. The factor of $m$ arises when you change variables from momentum to velocity.

Consider electron gas moving in 1D ring with length $L$(in thermodynamic limit the boundary effects are not important), with periodic
boundary condition, the single particle state can be written as:
\begin{align*}
\psi_{m}(x) & =e^{2\pi inx/L}\\
\end{align*}
in occupation number basis, of fermionic Fock space
\begin{align*}
V=span{|...,n_{i},...\rangle}
\end{align*}
Whose H and N eigenvalues are
\begin{align*}
E(\{n_{i}\})= & \sum_{i}\frac{n_{i}}{2m}\left(\frac{2\pi i\hbar}{L}\right)^{2}\\
N(\{n_{i}\})= & \sum_{i}n_{i}
\end{align*}
Thus the grand-canonical partition function in the occupation number basis is:
\begin{align*}
Z=\sum_{\{n_{i}=0/1\}} & \exp\left\{ -\beta\left[E(\{n_{i}\})-\mu N(\{n_{i}\})\right]\right\} \\
Z=\prod_{i}\sum_{n_{i}=0,1} & \exp\left\{ -\beta\left[\frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{2\pi i\hbar}{L}\right)^{2}-\mu\right]n_{i})\right\} \\
Z=\prod_{i} & 1+\exp\left\{ -\beta\left[\frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{2\pi i\hbar}{L}\right)^{2}-\mu\right]\right\} \\
\ln Z=\sum_{i}\ln & \left\{ 1+\exp\left\{ -\beta\left[\frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{2\pi i\hbar}{L}\right)^{2}-\mu\right]\right\} \right\} \\
k_{i}=\frac{2\pi i}{L}
\end{align*}
if $L$ are large enough (compare to the $1/k_{F}$) the lattice in
k-space will be dense, the sum can be approximated into integral, $\frac{L}{2\pi}$ factor come from the number of states in unit volume of k space
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i} & \rightarrow\frac{L}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk\\
\ln Z & =\frac{L}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk\ln\left(1+\exp(-\beta\left[\frac{m}{2}\left(\frac{k\hbar}{m}\right)^{2}-\mu\right]\right)\\
v= & \frac{k\hbar}{m}\\
\ln Z & =\frac{Lm}{2\pi\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dv\ln\left(1+\exp(-\beta\left[\frac{m}{2}v^{2}-\mu\right]\right)\\
N=\frac{\partial}{\partial(\beta\mu}\ln Z & =\frac{Lm}{2\pi\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dv\frac{\exp(-\beta\left[\frac{m}{2}v^{2}-\mu\right]}{1+\exp(-\beta\left[\frac{m}{2}v^{2}-\mu\right]}=\frac{Lm}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dv\frac{1}{\exp\beta\left[\frac{m}{2}v^{2}-\mu\right]+1}\\
n=\frac{N}{L}= & \frac{m}{2\pi\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dv\frac{1}{\exp\beta\left[\frac{m}{2}v^{2}-\mu\right]+1}
\end{align*}
Where in your case is the origin of $\frac{m}{2\pi\hbar}$ note that
here is one dimensional and didn't consider the spin degeneracy.
